# QML PathView: change current index of pathview via mouse wheel

Tags: qt, qml

I have created a path view with a delegate and model. Is it possible to change current index of the PathView via mouse wheel instead of mouse click drag?

Following is my PathView code:

```
PathView {
    id: pathView;
    anchors.fill: parent;
    model: sampleModel;
    delegate: delegate;
    path: Path {
        startX: 45; startY: 100
        PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 0.3 }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 0.1 }
        PathQuad { x: 45; y: 300; controlX: 45; controlY: 200 }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 1 }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 1 }
        PathQuad { x: 45; y: 500; controlX: 45; controlY: 400 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the the same problem. Here is my solution:
Every time a wheel event occurs, I in/decrement a "wheelIndex" and set the view.currentIndex to this value.
To reset the wheelIndex after the wheel usage, I use a timer:

```
PathView {
id: view
anchors.fill: parent
focus: true
model: monthModel
property int wheelIndex:- 1;
currentIndex: 0;

MouseArea {
anchors.fill: parent
preventStealing: true;
propagateComposedEvents: true

 Timer {
     id:wheelTimer
     interval: 200;
     running: false;
     repeat: false
     onTriggered: {
        view.wheelIndex = -1;
     }
 }

onWheel: {
    wheelTimer.start();

    if (view.wheelIndex === -1) {
        view.wheelIndex = view.currentIndex;
    }

    if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0) {
        view.wheelIndex++
        if (view.wheelIndex > view.model.count) {
            view.wheelIndex = 0;
        }

        view.currentIndex = view.wheelIndex;
    } else {
        view.wheelIndex--;
        if (view.wheelIndex < 0) {
            view.wheelIndex = view.model.count - 1;
        }

        view.currentIndex = view.wheelIndex;
    }
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

by adding a **MouseArea** as **child** to your **PathView** with **anchors.fill:parent** and implementing the **onWheel()** event as follow :

```
 PathView{
         id:view
         ...... 

    MouseArea{

       id:mouse
       anchors.fill: parent
       onWheel: 
            {
           if( wheel.angleDelta.y > 0 ) view.incrementCurrentIndex();
           else view.decrementCurrentIndex();
            }
    }
```

you'll get it working with both ,**mouse drag** and **mouse scroll (wheel)**.For more info look at [QtQuick 5.0: WheelEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-wheelevent.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this way has a problem: The speed of wheel scrolling by user is not affecting the speed of pathView. The reason is animating behavior of pathview.

Comment: I investigated little bit the **PathView** and noticed by means of  `PathView.moving` ,`PathView.dgragging` and `PathView.flicking` at the **Wheel event** (false all of them) that `PathView.incrementIndex()` and `PathView.decrementIndex()` don't emit the **flicking event**.Therefore we dont get the behaviour you want and the beautiful animation.

Comment: I thought of tricking it by setting `PathView.flicking` to `true` but it's a read_only and there is no setter available. hope this will enlighten your path.